# Why Gradle 'build' task is not up-to-date even there is no change in the source code?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I created a Gradle project for a spring application. My build.gradle is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath('org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.3')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'edge'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

bootRepackage {
    excludeDevtools = true
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-ribbon')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-redis')
    compile('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.session:spring-session')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket')
    compile('com.h2database:h2')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.RELEASE"
    }
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}
```

Then every time I ran `gradle build` without any changes in the source code, several tasks were always executed while I think they should be up-to-date:

```
➜  octopus git:(master) ✗
➜  octopus git:(master) ✗ gradle :edge:build
:edge:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:edge:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:edge:classes UP-TO-DATE
:edge:findMainClass
:edge:jar
:edge:bootRepackage
:edge:assemble
:edge:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:edge:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:edge:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:edge:test UP-TO-DATE
:edge:check UP-TO-DATE
:edge:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.773 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.13/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
➜  octopus git:(master) ✗ md5 edge/build/libs/edge-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
MD5 (edge/build/libs/edge-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) = d0ff71c362d089559bbc627e78e2247a
➜  octopus git:(master) ✗ gradle :edge:build
:edge:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:edge:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:edge:classes UP-TO-DATE
:edge:findMainClass
:edge:jar
:edge:bootRepackage
:edge:assemble
:edge:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:edge:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:edge:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:edge:test UP-TO-DATE
:edge:check UP-TO-DATE
:edge:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.579 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.13/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
➜  octopus git:(master) ✗ md5 edge/build/libs/edge-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
MD5 (edge/build/libs/edge-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) = d1c3fc5c9d0c00e0130c8c65f23b6466
➜  octopus git:(master) ✗
```

As you can see, tasks 'findMainClass', 'jar', 'bootRepackage', 'assemble', and 'build' are considered as non up-to-date and always executed. And each time the generated jar file is different, as they have different MD5 digest.

So, why Gradle behave like this? How can I make them all up-to-date and speed up the build process?

Answer (score 2):

By default, Spring Boot's `bootRepackage` task overwrites that jar that's created by the `jar` task. This means that the `jar` task is always considered to be out of date. You can avoid this by configuring `bootRepackage` with a classifier so that the repackaged fat jar is written to a separate location. For example:

```
bootRepackage  {
    classifier = 'exec'
}
```

You may also be interested in [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5861) which describes a number of improvements we'd like to make to Boot's Gradle plugin.

Comment: Thanks. What actually bother me is that, I use `com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin` to integrate with docker, which has a task to build docker image including the executable jar. Each time when I execute `gradle buildDockerImage` without change in source code, it will always build the docker image which is a time-consuming task.